# Unwind segue doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i'm doing an app that uses a TableViewController with a system of Adding/Editing items, using the same view. (however when you add an item the view is modal presented and when you edit it is shown)

I followed the great [starter tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1) from Apple so basically my Storyboard looks like this

[image: storyboard]

The segue going through the Navigation Controller is for adding and the other one is for editing. (I did everything according to the tutorial).

I did a segue between the Cancel item bar button and the exit icon of the ViewController and it works well when the view is modally presented (when I try to add an item).

However when I click on a cell to reach the view with the segue that shows it (to edit an item), both items in the navigation bar stop working. The `prepareForSegue` method is not called anymore. So I can't cancel or save.

I tried creating an unwind segue between the ViewController itself and the exit icon and to call it programmatically like this:

```
@IBAction func testButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("we're inside")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cancelSegue", sender: self)
    print("so what now")
}
```

and when I try to edit it and tapping the cancel button it results by just showing the two log messages and kind of skipping the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method. However adding still works fine.

Am I doing something wrong or have I misunderstood some basic notion about unwind segues?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like quite a strange solution to your problem. While I can't comment on specifically why your unwind segue isn't working in the second case, things will start to get quite complicated with dismissing the `New Program`segue since you're displaying it two different ways.

The common approach that we use is:

1. Use two completely different view controllers for creating and updating an assets. May be some duplicate code, but makes it slightly easier for other people to work on.
2. Use the same view controller for creating and updating buttons. If you're editing an item, you can pass it to the view controller with `prepareForSegue`. When the view controller loads, if an item is present, you can change the behaviour of the buttons, title etc. If no item is present, you know to create a new item.
3. For most implementations, it's much simpler to dismiss the views programatically. (i.e `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]` for modal views and `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` for just returning to a vc in the same navigation controller stack.

**Update**

Did you link the Cancel button to the exit icon on the first view controller, or the second view controller (the one with the cancel and save button)?

Comment: I'm gonna try to find another way using you approaches thanks, (I linked the cancel button and the exit icon on the 2nd view)

Comment: Ah okay, I believe the cancel button has to go to the exit icon on the **first** view for it to work correctly.